# Language picker with flag icon with Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would put a language picker in this section:

```
<section id="logo-section" class="text-center">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="logo text-center">
                        <h1>Batpeppa</h1>
                        <span>Web Designer Trio</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</section>
```

I would insert two flag icons under "Web Designer Trio" subtitle. 
I would use the **class="icon-flag"** from Bootstrap 3.

I think I have to use something like this:

```
<span class="icon-flag">
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: I don't know how to insert the language picker.

Comment: My code dowsen't work.
The flag is not shown..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the [native Bootstrap 3.x icons](http://getbootstrap.com/components/) are named `glyphicon-<name>`. So in your case:

```
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-flag"></i>
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-flag"></i>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lnke2j8q/). Your code does not work because you are referring to the "old" [Twitter Bootstrap 2.x icons](http://marcoceppi.github.io/bootstrap-glyphicons/), named `icon-<name>`. If you want to use those, you must download and include the `.png` and `.css` from [**here**](https://github.com/marcoceppi/bootstrap-glyphicons). Then you should be fine.

Comment: Great! I remembered only the old icons from Bootstrap.

Comment: @sharkbait - thank you for accepting the answer. I think there is a lot of people outthere, who are upgrading their bootstrap and is baffled about missing icons and so on. The team should have made a fallback, if you ask me.